# Go escape analysis, with var(s) declared as pointers

Tags: go, pointers, escape-analysis

```golang
func main() {
 var cs CustomStruct
 r := []byte{.......}
 err:=proto.Unmarshal(r, &cs)
 if err!=nil {
    panic(err)
  } 
}
```

When I run `go build -gcflags="-m" ./...` , I get

> moved to heap: CustomStruct

But with a small change, it does not get moved to the heap:

```golang
func main() {
 var cs *CustomStruct
 r := []byte{.......}
 err:=proto.Unmarshal(r, cs)
 if err!=nil {
    panic(err)
  } 
}
```

Now when I run the escape-analysis command, it doesn't say that `CustomStruct` gets moved to the heap. What exactly is going on, here?

Comment: `cs` is nil in your second implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the address of `cs` is sent to a function and that function may spawn goroutines that may hold a reference to `cs` after the function returns, it is moved to heap.

In the second case, `cs` is a pointer. There is no need to move the pointer itself to the heap, because that the function `Unmarshal` can refer to is the object pointed to by `cs`, not `cs` itself. You didn't show how `cs` is initialized, so this piece of code will fail, however if you initialize `cs` to point to a variable declared in that function, that object will likely end up in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

`proto.Unmarshal`

```
func Unmarshal(buf []byte, pb Message)
```

```
type Message interface {
    Reset()
    String() string
    ProtoMessage()
}
```

interface{} can be every type, It is difficult to determine the specific types of its parameters during compilation, and escape will also occur.

but if interface{} is a pointer, it just a pointer